# Using negative supply rail instead of ground in SMPS IC

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, solar-cell, negative-voltage

I'm working on a solar power inverter I noticed that all PWM ICs using negative 12 rail as a gnd...
As an example a PWM IC SG3524 which is used to convert batteries voltage to high dc bus voltage used -12 volt as a gnd input and 12 volt for vcc which in common is 24 volt
Why using negative rail instead of a gnd and a single 24 volt rail?
Is it related to isolate gnd of noise and interference (EMI)?
Even a flyback uc3845 which generates power rails for the whole circuit is powered of a negative -12 volt rail!
What is the purpose of this?

Comment: That sounds a bit weird... Could you please link the example circuits you've found?

Comment: Sometimes "-12V" is used to mean the negative side of the 12 volt supply, rather than being a separate negative supply.  Some study of the circuit will usually show whether the circuit really wants a single +12 supply or separate + and - 12V supplies, for a total of 24V.